# How to make a Static and Dynamic Button in Dynamic datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi I'm getting the wrong inputs with my datagridview. (see below picture)

[image]

I want it exactly to be like the picture below

[image]

So here is my database as you can see below

[image]

and here is my Code. So my code generates button and if i click it. It should generate the proper values in the datagridview.

```
object[] itemDetail;
object[] itemLi = itemsWS.searchItem("", "drinks", "all");
int x = 35;
int cleft = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < itemLi.Length; i++)
{
    itemDetail = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLi[i].ToString());
    Button myButton = new Button();
    myButton.Tag = i;
    myButton.Click += (senders, args) =>
    {
        var button = senders as Button;
        selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.ColumnCount = 4;
        selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Columns[0].Name = "Item Code";
        //selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Columns[1].Name = "description SCRAP";
        selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Columns[1].Name = "Each";
        selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Columns[2].Name = "Quantity";
        selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Columns[3].Name = "Amount";

        //this.selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Columns[1].Visible = false;

        string row1 = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLi[(int)button.Tag].ToString()).ToString();

        numericPopUp numPopUp = new numericPopUp();
        numPopUp.Show();
        selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Rows.Add(itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLi[(int)button.Tag].ToString()));
    };

    myButton.Text = itemDetail[1].ToString() + "\n  " + itemDetail[2].ToString();
    myButton.Top = cleft * 180;
    myButton.Left = 70;
    myButton.Location = new Point(x, cleft);
    myButton.Size = new Size(100, 60);
    drinksOrderManagementTab.Controls.Add(myButton);
    x += 135;

    if (x >= 537)
    {
        x = 35;
        cleft += 80;
    }
}
```

Please any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your row is doing just what you told it to do: it shows the given items. Your problem is, that these items come straight out of the database and include every column - without restrictions or reordering. That's why you see the column order reflected in your row (first item_code, then description and so on).

Easiest way here is to construct a new array including only the data you actually want to show in your row. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
object[] dbOutput = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLi[(int)button.Tag].ToString());
object[] items = new object[] {
    dbOutput[1], //description
    dbOutput[2]  //sale_price
    //and so on
};
selectedItenOutputOrderTabGrid.Rows.Add(items);
```

I'm quite sure there are advanced techniques and personally I would lay this off to when you select the data from the database, but this should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi. what if i dont have amount and quantity on the database. and I want to make it static.

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo Just insert them in your array: `object[] items = new object[] { dbOutput[1], dbOutput[2], 4, 20000};`